Cannot access JavaScript Modules from Cloudflare R2...Why am I getting CORS Errors?
I am using R2 to serve static files for my webpage index.html:

    <script type="module" src="{% static 'js/display.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="module" src="{% static 'js/run-model.js' %}"></script>    
    <script src="{% static 'js/file.js' %}"></script>

display.js
import { variable1, function1} from "./run-model.js";

run-model.js
import { variable2, function2} from "./display.js";

The site is able to load the js files, but then in addition it throws CORS errors for the modules as they try to import variables.

Access to script at 'https://<>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/bucket/js/display.js' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


GET https://<>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/bucket/js/display.js net::ERR_FAILED 400 (Bad Request)


Access to script at 'https://<>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/bucket/js/run-model.js' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


GET https://<>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com/bucket/js/run-model.js net::ERR_FAILED 400 (Bad Request)

I have tried adding a rule in Cloudflare to set an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to * AND ALSO set a CORS policy on the bucket for anything from my domain https://www.example.com.
But still the two failed items don't have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Also their Content-Type header is set as 'application/xml':


On Cloudflare dashboard go to the relevant R2 bucket's settings, and update the CORS policy to allow your hostname(s).
For example:
[
  {
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "http://localhost:3000",
      "https://my-app.pages.dev"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET"
    ],
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ]
  }
]

